# Подключение файла php в Controller и blade. Laravel

Tags: laravel

Всем привет. Подскажите пжл.
Я создал файл в директории App/Dictionary/ru.php
в нем находиться массивы данных, типа словаря.

```
$lg_day_week = array (
    1 => 'пн',
    2 => 'вт',
    3 => 'ср',
    4 => 'чт',
    5 => 'пт',
    6 => 'сб',
    7 => 'вс',);
```

1. в blade я могу его подключить: `<?php include app_path()."/dictionary/ru.php"; ?>`
2. как его подключить в контроллере?

мне выходит ошибка: ErrorException Undefined variable: $lg_day_week

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Я создал файл в директории App/Dictionary/ru.php в нем находиться массивы данных, типа словаря.

В ларавеле так делать нельзя. Удаляйте сразу этот файл. Все файлы локализации находятся по пути, `/resources/lang/en,ru и т.д` только там создаются данные массивы. Читаем данный [раздел документации](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization)

2. в blade я могу его подключить: .

В ларавеле и так делать нельзя! все подключения в блейде используются с помощью директив, `@extends @include @yield`. Отправка переменных на фронт осуществляется только через контроллер или конфиги и локализации или глобальное подключение. Подключением шаблона или `response` Читаем данный [раздел документации](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade) и [этот](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views)

3. как его подключить в контроллере?

После переписывания всего что описано выше, для получения значений для текущей локализации с выводом на фронт через контроллер используется фасад `Lang` или сразу в блейде с помощью хелпера `__('путь')` (например `__('messages.errors')`)

**Пример:**

```
// контроллер
function index()
{
    //файл lang/ru/dates.php
    $weeksName = Lang::get('dates.weeks');
}

// файл локализации

return [
    'weeks' => [
        1 => 'пн',
        2 => 'вт',
        3 => 'ср',
        4 => 'чт',
        5 => 'пт',
        6 => 'сб',
        7 => 'вс'
    ]
];
```

Comment: огромное спасибки! я сделал так: ```config("lg.shop.lg_type_organization")``` но хотелось бы сделать как Вы сказали. Дело в том, что если делать по вашему, если в массиве по ключу параметр отсутствует, то возвращается строка "lg.shop.lg_type_organization" - прям как оно написано текстом. А в моем случае, возвращается ПУСТО. Можно ли это как-то исправить, если делать по вашему?

Comment: @Den а как оно не может существовать? вы создали файл и записали туда все ключи которые должны переводиться на разные языки и получаете их. Как получить того чего нет? Эти файлы формируются заранее. Либо вы просто путь не правильно указали.  Если вы используете конфиг, то у данного метода вторым параметром передается значение по умолчанию, которое можете указать  в ручную. А так проверяйте правильность расположения файлов. По умолчанию локализация стоит "en" то есть вы должны кидать в папку "en" ваш новый файл с массивами, переключение локализации находится в файле конфига app вроде

Comment: то есть если у вас файл lg.php лежит в папке ru/lg.php а локализация "en" то он не найдет конечно же. Все файлы локализации должны быть идентичными, и отличаться в них может только текст. И кол-во файлов совпадать.